# xpath is correct for the element which I want to click on but when I am running the test I am getting this error: no such element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I should find a button and should click on it. I found the xpath of it (xpath is correct) but still I am getting the error as no such element

Comment: Some code/xml/html and the actual XPath you are trying would allow answering your question. In its current form it not possible for the community to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue with the xpath, please share the Xpath else install FirePath plugin in Firefox  which will enable you to test xpaths, cssselectors and sizzle.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/